# How to set the number of decimal places in scientific notation?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on python 2.7. I want to fix the number of decimal places in a number written in scientific notation like 1.32e6, but instead of using for example "%3f". I want to write something  like:

```
n=3
"%.nf"
```

where n is the number of decimal places, but it can be changed from my application.

Comment: _but it can be changed from my application._ What do you mean? Can you explain things a bit more? Also, may I ask why you're using Python 2?

Answer (score 3):

```py
n = 4
print("{0:.{1}f}".format(1.987213,n))
n = 5
print("{0:.{1}f}".format(1.987213,n))
```

---

Output

```
1.9872
1.98721
```

Answer (score 3):

```
i = 123456789
n = 3
print('{:.{n}e}'.format(i, n=n))
```

Output:

```
'1.235e+08'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```py
>>> a = 10e6
>>> n = 2
>>> '%.{}f'.format(n) % a
'10000000.00'
```

Or cast to float,

```py
>>> a = 10e6
>>> n = 2
>>> float('%.{}f'.format(n) % a)
10000000.0
```

If you want to return to scientific notation,

```py
>>> a = 103.023232
>>> n = 3
>>> '%.{}E'.format(n) % a
'1.030E+02'
```

Answer (score 1):

The old `printf`-style formatting operator supports this, though you'll probably want to use the newer `format` method.

```
>>> n = 3
>>> "%.*f" % (n, 3.14159)
'3.142'
```

When you use `*` as the precision, the value to use precedes the floating-point value in the tuple on the RHS.

Comment: They are, but the question is tagged `python-2.7`, so we're limited to the `format` method and the `%` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you every body for the answers. I tried the method of Ajay Dabas and that worked for me perfectly. This example is going to be used in a major (but easy) application. The complete code with the improved solution is:

`enter code here`entrada_n= "Ingrese n:"
  `enter code here`n= input (entrada_n)

`enter code here`entrada_numero="Ingrese numero:"
  `enter code here`numero=input(entrada_numero)

`enter code here`print("{0:.{1}f}".format(numero,n))
  `enter code here`print("{0:.{1}e}".format(numero,n))